# Whats the easiest way to split an array based on the day of the week?

Tags: powershell

I have an array of users that I'd like to process a part of in a powershell script each day of the week.

To get the first 1/7 of the array I could use this:

`Foreach ($user in $Users[0..($users.count/7)])`

That's the part I would want to process on mondays. Is there an easy way to code this so the first seventh is processed if the script runs on a monday, the second seventh is processed if the script runs on a tuesday and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Since .Net has a nice [enum for days of week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8), let's leverage it with index modulo.

Assuming you don't care about which elements are processed as long as about 1/7th of elements are processed, we can process for every nth cell. The nth is picked by taking a modulus of weekday. For example, let's process cells that are Thursday entries. Since Thursday enum value is 4, by taking the modulo of index and Thursday, we will pick every fourth element. Like so,

```
function do_stuff {
  param([DayOfWeek]$dd, $item)
  $daytoday=(get-date).DayOfWeek
  if($dd -ne $daytoday) { "$dd is not $daytoday, not processing!"} 
  else { write-host "doing $dd stuff for $item" }
}
# Sample array that's long enough
$array= @(1..31)

for([int]$i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; ++$i){
  # When $i>6, modulo is needed to convert the index into weekday
  do_stuff $($i%6)  $array[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose another strategy starting from `[int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek` (or from the same number `(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__`). For instance, today (`2019-10-31`) you process every `4th`, `11th`, `18th`, … user (zero-based, of course):

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek          # Thursday
[int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek     # 4
for ($i =[int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek; $i -lt $users.Count; $i+=7) {
    # process user $users[$i]
}
```

The following code snippet shows an example: defines a fictive array of users and enumerates their processing each day of week (`0..6`):

```
$users=65..(65+23) | ForEach-Object { 
    ([string][char]$_) +([string][char]$_).ToLower()
}
0..6 | ForEach-Object {
    '{0,10}: {1}' -f (
        [System.Enum]::GetNames('System.DayOfWeek')[$_]), 
        ( $(for ($i =$_; $i -lt $users.Count; $i+=7) {$users[$i]}) -join ', ' )
}
```

Result:

```
D:\PShell\SO\58640469.ps1
```

> ```
>     Sunday: Aa, Hh, Oo, Vv
>     Monday: Bb, Ii, Pp, Ww
>    Tuesday: Cc, Jj, Qq, Xx
>  Wednesday: Dd, Kk, Rr
>   Thursday: Ee, Ll, Ss
>     Friday: Ff, Mm, Tt
>   Saturday: Gg, Nn, Uu
> ```